# how to maintain case of attribute name without changing to lower case in html agility pack

Tags: html-agility-pack

i want to maintain case of attribute name without changing to lower case

when i load xml in HTMLAgility pack attribute name changed into lowercase like this

`<Author affiliationids="Aff1" correspondingaffiliationid="Aff1">`
i want output like this

`<Author AffiliationIDS="Aff1" CorrespondingAffiliationID="Aff1">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, unless you change the source (the Html Agility Pack is open source, so you're free to go). it's by design, as it was designed to handle HTML, and HTML is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 16):

It is now officially fixed and [promised to be included in next release](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/25278)

As for now you can [download](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/99962) source and build it yourself.

To prevent lowercase of all attributes use:

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.OptionOutputOriginalCase = true;
```

Comment: but attributes are still getting converted to lower case. In my company code, all attributes are hardcoded for validation which is causing exception. Any other option to retain the case of attributes as well

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I dont know if it is about new version or something, but I hit the exact problem you had and by reading the innerhtml, i found out it is loaded ok and it's not a problem of reader but the writer.

So instead of using the writeHtml command, I just pulled the output by using DocumentNode.OuterHtml property and it all worked great!

Try it and you will see!