# Escaping inner quotes in attributes in malformed xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have the following third party xml containing the malformed XML snippet and I am trying to use XmlTextReader to read through it.

```
   <ReplacementDefinitions>
        <Def key="EnclosingFunction.name" value="_jspService(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Upload_Service"].ToString())"/>
        <Def key="PrimaryCall.name" value="print()"/>
        <Def key="PrimaryLocation.file" value="Error.jsp"/>
        <Def key="PrimaryLocation.line" value="20"/>
        <LocationDef path="webapp/jsp/common/Error.jsp" line="20" lineEnd="20" colStart="27" colEnd="0" key="PrimaryLocation"/>
      </ReplacementDefinitions>
```

XmlTextReader is throwing the exception:

```
'Upload_Service' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 44126, position 123.
```

Its getting hung up on the quotes in: ["Upload_Service"]. Any ideas on how I can escape these quotes so that XmlTextReader can parse the data?

Comment: The general rule is, if your data isn't XML, then don't attempt to use XML tools to process it. You need to use non-XML tools to preprocess it into well-formed XML first. The detailed repair strategy will depend on the detail of the faults that are present.

Comment: Bummer - I checked it with single quotes, instead of double quotes' around `Upload_Service` and it loads fine.  If only...

Comment: You could try &quot;Upload_Service&quot; . No idea whether it will work though. One instance of malformed xml is usually followed by several more in my experience. I'd be staring angrily at whoever produced this instead of working my arse off trying to rescue it.

Comment: I thought I might sneak it through using powershell.  I extracted the text to a variable, but as soon as I tried to cast the variable to XML, I got the same exception, which makes sense, I guess, since it's probably using the same .Net gyrations under the covers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to parse your xml with html parsers(like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)) which are more fault tolerant.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(xml);

var defs = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("def")
        .ToDictionary(d=>d.Attributes["key"].Value,d=>d.Attributes["value"].Value);
```

Comment: The XML in the question can at least be loaded by `HtmlAgilityPack`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/unHakF.  You may want to set [`doc.OptionOutputOriginalCase`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14232505/3744182) to preserve the casing of XML node and attribute names.  The result will be additional attributes inserted in the attribute list, if you know the XML schema you can look for unexpected attributes and append their names & values to the preceding attribute's value, then generate new XML with `doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml`.